# Width 100% and height 100% not working in chrome

Tags: c#, arrays

I don't really understand arrays and i need to create a variable of type 'array of songs' then initialize it to a new Array so it can store 4 references to Songs. How would i then create a loop that would run enough times to fill the array whilst calling the InputSOngDetails() method and store the return value in that method?

```
namespace Songs
```

{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) {

```
        InputSongDetails();
    }


    static Song InputSongDetails()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("What is the name of your song");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("What is the artists name");
        string artist = Console.ReadLine();

        int records;
        Console.WriteLine("How many records did it sell");
        while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out records) || records < 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("That is not valid please enter a number");
        }
        return new Song(name, artist, records);
    }
}
```

}

This is my Songs class if needed

namespace Songs
{
    class Song
    {
        string name;
        string artist;
        int copiesSold;

```
    public Song(string name, string artist, int copiesSold)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.artist = artist;
        this.copiesSold = copiesSold;
    }

    public Song()
    {
    }

    public string GetArtist()
    {
        return artist;
    }

    public string GetDetails()
    {
        return $"Name: {name} Artist: {artist} Copies Sold: {copiesSold},";
    }

    public string GetCertification()
    {
        if (copiesSold<200000)
        {
            return null;
        }
        if (copiesSold<400000)
        {
            return "Silver";
        }
        if (copiesSold<600000)
        {
            return "gold";
        }
        return "Platinum";  
    }
}
```

}

Comment: If your goal is to have each video stretch to fill the viewport, you can use vh and vw units. 1vh is effectively 1% of the screen height. 1vw = 1% of screen width.

Comment: Maybe try using max-width / max-height values combined with width / height = 100%. This will cause the iframes to fill their container up to the defined max. It will also allow them to shrink for smaller screens.

Answer (score 0):

Declare width / height as 100%, but use max-width / max-height to constrain to your desired dimensions.

```
<iframe style="width: 100%; height: 100%; max-width: 700px; max-height: 400px"></iframe>
```